# How to change the default program to open any Word documents, using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application, I want to open Word documents in Word 2007 or above, whether or not the default program for opening Word documents is Word 2007. Even if the default program to open Word documents is Open Office, I want to open them in Word 2007+.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really have anything to do with WPF.

You'll need to now where Word is installed or add the the folder in which it is located to the Path environment variable.

Assuming your file name variable is called fileName and the full path of winword.exe is stored in wordPath (or winword.exe is in the Path), you would need to do something like this -

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                                         {
                                             CreateNoWindow = false,
                                             Arguments = fileName,
                                             FileName = wordPath
                                         };
Process wordProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Note 1 - your fileName is passed directly to Word. If the path contains white spaces you'll have to wrap it in "". Something like

```
fileName = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", 
                                fileName.StartsWith("\"") ? "" : "\"", 
                                fileName,
                                fileName.EndsWith("\"") ? "" : "\"");
```

Note 2 - Word has other command line arguments for different purposes, for other uses see  here  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210565.